# Testing server-side/client-side coffeescript code

Tags: unit-testing, testing, node.js, coffeescript

What do you use to test CofeeScript in the browser and in the server (node.js)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I use [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit) to test my CoffeeScript code in both a browser and via commandline; you can use [node-qunit](https://github.com/kof/node-qunit) to test on the server. There are other solutions out there, but QUnit fits my needs pretty well and can be quite elegantly utilized from CoffeeScript:

```
module 'MyModule'

test 'MyModule.someFunction', ->
    ok someValue
    strictEqual anotherValue, 323
```

QUnit, additionally, has support for asynchronous tests, which makes it suitable not only for testing AJAX in the browser but also for testing various asynchronous fixtures in node.js like I/O.

Comment: +1. QUnit is almost certainly the most popular JS testing framework out there, thanks to its association with jQuery (which it does **not** depend on). It's simple, robust, and feature-rich enough for nearly every project.

Answer (score 2):

I use [jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) in both the browser and in node.js (via [jasmine-node](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node)).  I also like the [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) plugin.  Jasmine has some async support built it as well.  The jasmine syntax is very nice in CoffeeScript whereas its a little verbose in javascript with so many nested functions.